# Error executing JSON based Restful WCF Service

Tags: json, web-services, wcf, rest, restsharp

I am trying to write a json based restful WCF service. When i execute it using RestSharp i get a null response with the following Error in the ErrorException and the ErrorMessage.
Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

Status Code is BadRequest

The data object is created as

```
[DataContract]
public class User
{        
    [DataMember]
    public string first_name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string last_name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string email_address { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public List<UserAddress> Address; //do not serialize this in the data contract
}

[DataContract]
public class UserAddress
{
    [DataMember]
    public string line_1_address { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string state { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string PostalArea { get; set; }
}
```

The service code is

```
   [ServiceContract]
    public interface IUserService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        User AddUser(User user);
    }


    public class UserService : IUserService
    {
        [WebInvoke(Method = "PUT",
           RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           UriTemplate = "User/")]
        public User AddUser(User user)
        {
            return new User();
        }
    }
```

The service is hosted in a Web App.

I have a c# client based on RestSharp

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        User u = new User();
        u.first_name = "testFirst";
        u.last_name = "testLast";

        UserAddress ua = new UserAddress();
        ua.line_1_address = "line 1";
        ua.PostalArea = "08648";
        ua.state = "NJ";

        u.Address = new List<UserAddress>();
        u.Address.Add(ua);

        RestSharp.RestClient client = new RestSharp.RestClient("http://localhost/TestWCHHost/User.svc");
        var request = new RestRequest(String.Format("User/"), Method.PUT);
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        request.AddObject(u);
        var response = client.Execute<User>(request);
    }
```

The web config changes are as

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>

      <!-- User Service -->
      <service name="TestService.UserService" behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="TestService.IUserService" behaviorConfiguration="web">
        </endpoint>
      </service>

    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="serviceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Unable to figure whats going on. Any clues.

Comment: Hard to spot the error. How does your web.config file look like? I would recommend using a web debugger like fiddler2 or like to check out how the web request looks like... since the error message you get is bad request. Postman could also be an alternative to write the request in C#...

Comment: Hi Jocke. I have attached the web config entry. I will look at fiddler. Just wondering the config entry would tell u anything.

Comment: are you sure your service is running on: http://localhost/TestWCHHost/User.svc if you are using cassini it normally runs on a specific port (like http://localhost:1188/TestWCHHost/User.svc or so)?